# Angular UI Bootstrap typeahead-append-to

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-ui-typeahead

I'm trying to append the Angular UI Typeahead control to a custom element in my HTML.  The docs state this:

> typeahead-append-to $ (Default: null) - Should the typeahead popup be appended to an element instead of the parent element?

I cannot for the life of me figure what to set this value to!  I have tried all combinations of '#elementId' and '.elementClass' but still having no luck.

I can append to the body no probs with typeahead-append-to-body="true", but that's not what I want to do.

Help please!

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***OUTDATED SEE THE EDIT SECTION FOR LATEST APPROACH***

The typeahead-append-to attribute expects you to reference an element in your controller and bind to that:

```
$scope.appendToElement = window.document.querySelector('body');

<input uib-typeahead="val for val in vals" typeahead-append-to="appendToElement" />
```

The code in the typeahead directive that reads the attribute and appends the element can be seen [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/typeahead/typeahead.js#L490)

***EDIT***

The directive has been updated and will accept a selector string like so:

```
<input uib-typeahead="val for val in vals" typeahead-append-to="'#appendToElement'" />
```

Comment: My only issue with this is having elements in your controller. Your controller should be clean of HTML elements, etc..

Comment: In Angular 1.5, this is unfortunately not allowed as you cannot pass DOM elements via angular expressions. Angular throws the following error: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/isecdom

Answer (score 4):

> *(**UPDATE:** The user-selected answer to this question has since been updated with an addendum that includes the current, correct way to accomplish this.)*

So, sorry to necropost, but I was looking at this today and thinking that the selected solution seemed strange, and banged my head against it for a few hours.  While the selected solution *may* have been true at one point, as of right now it is not at all necessary to reference a scope property that references a DOM object.  All you have to do is pass a selector (I tried an ID-- other selectors might get sketchy) but wrap it in single-quotes inside your double-quotes in the attribute.  So:

```
<input uib-typeahead="val for val in vals" typeahead-append-to="#myTargetElement" />
```

*won't* work but

```
<input uib-typeahead="val for val in vals" typeahead-append-to="'#myTargetElement'" />
```

*will* work.  Note the extra single-quotes: " **'** #myTargetElement **'** ".

Comment: Th code that reads in the append to attribute value is here: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/typeahead/typeahead.js#L77  where originalScope.$eval(attrs.typeAheadAppendTo) tries to read the value from the consuming scope.  And here: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/typeahead/typeahead.js#L504 is where it appends the popup to the append to element.  So it's using your selector '#myTargetElement' in the angular.element() method.  The single quotes wrapped around your attribute value tell Angular it is a string literal and don't bother parsing.

Comment: Hence my edit where I demonstrate how to use a selector string wrapped in single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

My little directive:

```
angular.module('typeahead-append-to-selector', ['ui.bootstrap'])
angular.module('typeahead-append-to-selector').directive('typeaheadAppendToSelector', [function () {
    return {
        controller: ['$scope', '$attrs', function ($scope, $attrs) {
            $scope.typeaheadAppendTo = document.querySelector($attrs.typeaheadAppendToSelector);
        }]
    }
}])
```

then add these attrs to the input:

```
typeahead-append-to="typeaheadAppendTo" typeahead-append-to-selector="#appendToThis"
```

Hope that helps someone